Buscar y filtrar en un Datagridview con Enlace de Datos Modelado EF6 VS2022
Holas, soy nueva en EF con modelado de datos. Seguí el tutorial de Microsoft Databinding with WinForms (Enlace de datos con WinForms). Pero necesito buscar y filtrar a través de un textbox y un botón. Pero he ensayado muchos ejemplos, hasta de los mismos tutoriales de Microsoft y no he podido. Gracias por su ayuda. El siguiente es el código que tengo:
namespace Presentacion.FrmGeneral
{
    public partial class frmEjemplo : Form
    {
        TiendaContext _context;
        public frmEjemplo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            _context = new TiendaContext();
            _context.CategoriaConsulta.Load();

            this.categoriaConsultaBindingSource.DataSource =
                _context.CategoriaConsulta.Local.ToBindingList();
        }

        protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnClosing(e);
            this._context.Dispose();
        }

        private void frmEjemplo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {}

        private void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {}
     }
}


Mira a ver si esto te vale, es algo más "manual" pero funciona:
    # Ponemos en minuscula para asegurarnos que las mayusculas no juegan malas pasadas

    string busqueda = textBox1.Text.ToLower();

    # bindingList es tu lista original de datos

    var filtro = bindingList.Where(item => item.Nombre.ToLower().Contains(busqueda)).ToList();

    # MyClass es la clase de los objetos en tu lista

    dataGridView1.DataSource = new BindingList<MyClass>(filtro);

Espero que te valga, un saludo.

Holas, realicé unos ajustes que se me diran se pueden mejorar, pero toy aprendiendo. Muchas gracias...
private void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
_context = new TiendaContext();
_context.CategoriaConsulta.Load();
string busqueda = txbBuscar.Text;
var filtros= _context.CategoriaConsulta.Local.ToBindingList();
  var filtro = filtros.Where(item => 
  Item.Nombre.ToLower().Contains(busqueda)).ToList();
  dgvEjemploCategoria.DataSource = new BindingList<CategoriaConsulta>(filtro);  

}

No se si te he entendido bien del todo, pero para hacer una búsqueda de un textbox y un boton para que filtre el DataGridView sería algo así, poner este código en el botón btnBuscar:
string busqueda = textBox1.Text;

(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Nombre LIKE '%{0}%'", busqueda);

Si no fuera eso tendrías que especificar más.

dataGridView1.DataSource NO es un DataTable, es del tipo BindingList

Gracias, por tu ayuda, pero aunque la realicé me imagino que por ser modelado y además EF6 no traía datos porque no maneja DataTable es un BindingList
